# Any way to award a bounty to an editor?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I edited this question: [Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50054/does-casting-a-spell-from-an-item-allow-you-to-apply-class-abilities-that-are-us) and placed a bounty.  No new answers have been offered.  The only person who has really made any contribution is Dyndrilliac who edited prior answers.  The OP, although active on the site, has shown no interest.  Is there any way I can award the bounty to Dyndrilliac, who is the only person who contributed anything of use since the bounty was posted?  If not I will just let the bounty expire unawarded.

Answer (score 3):

A bounty can only go to one of the answers and its owner, so there's no way to give it to a helpful editor. I suppose you could persuade them to write their own answer, and then you would be able to.

(If you don't awared the bounty, half its value will automatically be awarded to the top-voted positive-scored answer at the time that was posted during the bounty period. If nothing meets those criteria it vanishes.)

On the plus side, the bounty *did* do its job of improving the answers. And an editor who helps to improve others' answers is usually doing it for their own satisfaction, since there are [only](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/3/editor) [a few](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) [rewards](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/copy-editor) for editing. So really, everyone still wins. :)

Comment: I kind of figured as much, but it was worth asking.  There is no answer that will qualify for the automatic bounty award, so it will just vanish.